# $group in range in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am building a Game application whose database is in `Mongodb`. I have a model for setting ranks  to players.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Ranks Schema -- Sub Schema of ContestsType
const rankSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  rank:{
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },    
  pAmt:{
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});


// ContestsType Schema
const ContestsTypeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  contestTypeName:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },    
  noOfWinners:{
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  ranks : [rankSchema]
});
```

> This is sample data for the above schema :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a83e99e64b803361cd82e7c"), 
    "noOfWinners" : 15.0, 
    "ranks" : [
        {
            "rank" : 1.0, 
            "pAmt" : 1000.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 2.0, 
            "pAmt" : 500.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 3.0, 
            "pAmt" : 50.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 4.0, 
            "pAmt" : 50.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 5.0, 
            "pAmt" : 50.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 6.0, 
            "pAmt" : 25.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 7.0, 
            "pAmt" : 25.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 8.0, 
            "pAmt" : 25.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 9.0, 
            "pAmt" : 25.0
        }, 
        {
            "rank" : 10.0, 
            "pAmt" : 25.0
        }
    ], 
    "contestTypeName" : "20 Teams | 15 Winners",
}
```

As You can see i have Ranks and With Prize amount i want to group these into ranges i.e Prize amount for Rank 1 is 1000, Rank 2 Is 500 but for Ranks 3-5 the prize amount is 50.

> So i want to display ranks to users in range format i.e

```
Rank 1 : 1000
Rank 2 : 500
Rank 3-5 : 50
Rank 5-10 : 25
```

This is Mongo DB aggregate pipeline i have written

```
db.contestTypes.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $match: {
            _id : ObjectId("5a83e99e64b803361cd82e7c"),
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$ranks",
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $group: {

                  _id : "$ranks.pAmt"


        }
    },

]
```

);

> This Gives Me Following Result At least

[image]

Comment: simply sort them in ascending order ? No ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey ...can you tell me in more detail ?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the complete output required. Sorry `sort` won't help

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **`bucket`** aggregation stage introduced in **MongoDB** 3.4

This allows you to group your data by ranges defined in `boundaries`.

First, use **`$unwind`** to unwind the array, and then apply **`$bucket`**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        "$unwind": "$ranks"
    },
    {
        "$bucket": {
            "groupBy": "$ranks.rank",
            "boundaries": [1, 2, 5, 10, 15],
            "default": 0,
            "output": {
                "pAmt": {
                    "$first": "$ranks.pAmt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

this output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "pAmt": 1000
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "pAmt": 500
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "pAmt": 50
  },
  {
    "_id": 10,
    "pAmt": 25
  }
]
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/v3ZoV8bhlVS](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v3ZoV8bhlVS)

Comment: will try that and revert